# How to count the number of levels of child nodes while reading an XML file using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an XML file having multiple nodes in a multi dimensional tree structure. How to find out the depth of this structure using excel vba. The Structure would be as follows:
   . ...... n levels  ........n levels

Please find my code snippet below:

```
Sub ChildNodesCount()

    ButtonOneClick = True
    Dim XmlDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument

    Fname = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="xml files (*.xml), *.xml", MultiSelect:=False)

    Set XmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument

    XmlDoc.async = False
    XmlDoc.validateOnParse = False
    XmlDoc.Load (Fname)

    Dim xmlNodeList As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim Node As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode

    Set xmlNodeList = XmlDoc.SelectNodes("//myNodeName")

    For Each Node In xmlNodeList
        Call ListNodes(Node)
    Next

End Sub

Public Function ListNodes(ByRef n As IXMLDOMNode)

     Dim n2 As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
     MsgBox "FirstMessage" & n.nodeName

     If n.HasChildNodes() Then
        MsgBox n.nodeName & "has child nodes"

        For Each n2 In n.ChildNodes
           ListNodes (n2)
        Next

        MsgBox "Done listing child nodes for " & n.nodeName

     End If
End Function
```

Comment: Maybe use regular expressions to search the whole document for Node in a chevron. If you hit ```</``` reset the count?

Comment: Just loop the nodes recursively and keep track of the level.  In VBA you can program that using `Microsoft XML V6.0` reference.

Comment: Thanks for the update Ron! I have tried recursive looping of nodes and struck with below error message --> Compile Error: user-defined type not defined
Please find my code snippet included in the question above.Please help!

Comment: Can you provide a sample XML snippet? Depending on its structure, a XPath query might be able to achieve the desired outcome, rather than recursively traversing the XML in code.

Comment: If getting user type not defined you likely haven't added the right reference via tools > references.

Comment: Compile Error was finally fixed after modifying the function arguments declaration as follows: Public Function ListNodes(ByRef n As IXMLDOMNode)